# What is the Islamic point of view about taking balance as loan in cell phones? Does that count in interest?

Tags: fiqh, riba

When we take loans, a particular network provides us loans but then they deduct more credit after we recharge. What is the Islamic point of view about taking balance as loan in cell phones? Does that count in interest?

Comment: It's not a loan. The telecom company is selling you a service at a premium price in return for late payment. (Source: a fatwa I read recently in Arabic but can't remember the source)

Answer (score 1):

From the moment I started reading the Quran and taking an interest in following Islam and the Prophet (saws) I stopped using that "loan" services. If the operator had debited the same amount as was credited there I would see no problem. Mainly because of this ayat:

> Those who consume interest cannot stand [on the Day of Resurrection]
>   except as one stands who is being beaten by Satan into insanity. That
>   is because they say, "Trade is [just] like interest." But Allah has
>   permitted trade and has forbidden interest. So whoever has received an
>   admonition from his Lord and desists may have what is past, and his
>   affair rests with Allah . But whoever returns to [dealing in interest
>   or usury] - those are the companions of the Fire; they will abide
>   eternally therein. [2|275](https://quran.com/2/275)

Whether or not to follow the recommendation is a choice that the person should make, but by following the recommendation the financial benefit will be entirely yours. And I noticed that benefit from the moment I stopped doing it.